# How access to TextScores in Aggregations using SpringBoot for MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have an aggregation for MongoDB. In this aggregation i have and `TextCriteria`. I want access to its score using `{ $meta: "textScore" }`. But unfortunately, there isn't any method for doing this in the `ProjectionOperation`. My question is how i can project the text search scores in Spring-boot data jpa?

**Note:** I know I can use `TextQuery` and `sortyByScore` function. I don't want that!

**Edit**
I found the answer: You can use `addExpression` and add meta to it:

```java
Aggregation.project("id", "title").andExpression("{$meta: \"textScore\"}").as("textScore")
```

Good luck!